# Append element after last element in a row of floating elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have following mark up, a wrapper which can hold a dynamic number of floating elements. 
A max of 3 elements could be placed side by side (= 1 row)

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
</div>
```

The floating elements have a click event (jQuery) where a new element should be added after the last element of the row the clicked element "is in". So if for example I click on the 1. element i end up withthis:

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="addElement"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
</div>
```

or if i click on the 5th element I get

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="addElement"></div>
    <div class="floatLeft"></div>
</div>
```

and so on.

I thought of using the nth-child selector, but I can't get it work properly.

**Edit:**
I don't want to wrap every 3 .floatLeft elements in a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

on Click , do this -

```
$('.floatLeft').on('click',function(){
     $(this).closest('.wrapper').append("<div class='addElement'></div>");
});
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7hh/2/

Comment: This would append it after the last in above example the 7th .floatLeft so at the end of .wrapper. I needed as in the examples if I click First, second or third .floatLeft append after the third. If I click on fourth, fifth, sixth .floatLeft after sixth .floatLeft and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.floatLeft').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<div class="addElement"></div>');
});
```

[And the jsFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/qrpXZ/)